# psexec process not visible when logging on to machine

Tags: remote-desktop, process, psexec

I am running a command to open a firefox browser on some windows machines:

```
psexec @VMS.txt -u user -p password -d "c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

when I log via remote desktop into one of those machines, I don't see the firefox window. But, when I look in the task manager's process tab I do see the firefox.exe process. Why is that, and how do I fix it so that when I login to the machine I will see firefox?

Answer (score 3):

I needed to add -i to the command:

```
psexec @VMS.txt -u user -p password -d -i "c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

That solved it

Comment: thanks for this, i was using psexec this way the other day and wondering what i was doing wrong.